# Will unity performance improve in natty or remain slow?

Tags: unity, performance

There are some apps developed by canonical that are way too slow. This are USC and Unity. Unity in 10.10 is insanely slow (compared to GNOME which isn't actually a very fast DE) and totally unusable for a netbook (i'ts funny because its targeted for netbooks usage)

Will this get as good as GNOME in natty, or remain the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until now Unity has used the **Mutter** window manager, which is the next generation of GNOME's *Metacity* and incorporates *Clutter*. However this has shown itself to have mixed hardware support - while it works fine on some machines, it is (almost) unusable on others.

However Canonical has already ported Unity to **Compiz**, which has been the default window manager in Ubuntu for the last three years. This should lead to far better performance and hardware support - if you current machine can run Visual Effects (enabled in System->Preferences->Appearance->Visual Effects) then the new version of Unity should run fine.

Comment: AFAIK mutter and compiz are window managers. In unity, not only opening windows was slow, but also the unity interface itself. Will this be improved also by compiz?

Comment: @Ignacio Based on my understanding of how windows are drawn (and interfaces) yes, this should be improved greatly when the Compiz version is released.

Answer (score 2):

Unity will be ported to Compiz for 11.04, which should help performance quite a bit. Also, according to [Rick Spencer's blog](http://theravingrick.blogspot.com/2010/10/this-is-it.html), Canonical plans to do quite a bit of other performance work this cycle.