# Installed Unity on my desktop PC and it is very laggy and annoying

Tags: 10.10, unity

I just installed Ubuntu Unity on my desktop PC and it is very lag and annoying! Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install, the netbook version or the compiz version?

Comment: Not quite a dupe but the answers here should help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9932/will-unity-performance-improve-in-natty-or-remain-slow

Comment: It happened to me too, simply, your card isn't supported!

Answer (score 4):

Unity has known performance problems due to the mutter window manager. For this reason, Unity is [switching to compiz](http://www.jonobacon.org/2010/10/25/ubuntu-11-04-to-ship-unity/) next release - Ubuntu 11.04. You are probably better off waiting until then before using it.

Reporting a bug may help the developers. To do this press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter: `ubuntu-bug unity`. Follow the prompts from there.

You can get a similar interface to the Unity dock with applications such as [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki).

Answer (score -1):

You are probably experiencing a isolated problem. Try to report a bug at [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/), and don't forget to offer details like: your hardware, devices, and how did you installed Unity.

Good luck!

Comment: Also mention which version of ubuntu you installed.